# libxslt is missing while installing ruby gem nokogiri

Tags: ruby, rubygems, nokogiri, gitlab, libxslt

I recognize that this is a duplicate question however all the other answers I've found related to this issue have not seemed to help me...

I'm installing `GitLab` and running through the gem dependencies when it hits the `NokoGiri` gem requirement and fails with the following info:

```
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
extconf.rb:10:in `<main>': Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
extconf.rb:10:in `<main>': Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config. 
extconf.rb:11:in `<main>': Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
checking for libxml/parser.h... yes
checking for libxslt/xslt.h... yes
checking for libexslt/exslt.h... yes
checking for iconv_open() in iconv.h... yes
checking for xmlParseDoc()... -lxml2
checking for xsltParseStylesheetDoc()... -lxslt
-----
libxslt is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
-----
```

So, this error leads me down the path of attempting to install `libxslt` with the following command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libxslt1-dev' instead of 'libxslt-dev'
libxslt1-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 146 not upgraded.
```

So what gives?  NokoGiri is needing this package, but the package is already installed!! I can't seem to get past this issue, any help out there?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try Nokogiri 1.6.0.rc1, which bundles libxml2 and libxslt in the gem. This should address your installation problem:

```
gem install nokogiri --pre
```

should do the trick.

Comment: What about a gem that depends on nokogiri 1.5.x?

Comment: aws-sdk (~> 1.24.0) ruby depends on
      nokogiri (< 1.6.0, >= 1.4.4) ruby    . :( this is like the third time I go through this same problem. Usually my solving procedure means trying a lot of stuff until one works.

Answer (score 40):

first make sure you have all the dependencies, as mentioned in "[Installing Nokogiri with RVM on Ubuntu](http://web.archive.org/web/20140221084907/http://www.andrewsturges.com/2011/09/installing-nokogiri-with-rvm-on-ubuntu.html)" (which mentions the very same error message)

> I have no idea why it can't find the package "libxslt". Instead of worrying about that, I'm going to install the dependencies listed on [Nokogiri GitHub page](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri):

```
$ sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libxslt1-dev' instead of 'libxslt-dev'
libxslt1-dev is already the newest version.
libxml2-dev is already the newest version.
```

> That appears to have worked well enough, so I press on. The next step is install the actual Nokogiri gem. The instructions say to use "sudo gem install nokogiri", but because I'm using RVM, I drop the "sudo" part:

```
$ gem install nokogiri
```

---

Considering "[Fresh install of RVM in Ubuntu isn't letting me install gems (zlib error)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6920623/6309)", since you have `libxslt1-dev` (and not `libxslt-dev`), you might considering recompiling your ruby.
(a bit like in "[How to get Readline support in IRB using RVM on Ubuntu 11.10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10765944/6309)")

Comment: Nokogiri github page no longer references this, but when setting up a dev environment for an old project.  However, your answer was exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Jason Thank you. I have restored the first link.

Answer (score 11):

Try installing dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev
```

Answer (score 11):

Maybe this will be helpful for other people: 
If you recieve error:

```
libxslt is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
```

you need to install also the devel version of libxslt

`apt-get install libxslt-dev`

or in CentOS

`yum install libxslt-devel`

Comment: Thanks, dude!
You saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

Choose and Install suitable library from below as per your Linux flavor:-

> - deb: **libxslt1-dev** (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
> - rpm: **libxslt-devel** (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
> - csw: **libxslt_dev** (Solaris)

Install with an appropriate command like apt-get, yum, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install a previous version of nokogiri, installing Nokogiri 1.6.0.rc1 would not do the trick.

You must install the `libxslt` separetly:

> sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev

After that run again your command:
(in my case)

> gem install nokogiri -v '1.5.11'